# How to get the current monitor resolution or monitor name (LVDS, VGA1, etc)

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, resolution

I would like to get the resolution of the current monitor (the screen from where I run the script) or the name of the screen (LVDS, VGA1, etc).

If I can't get the resolution but only the monitor name, I could grep 'xrandr -q' output to get current resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do this by a combination of `xrandr` and `xwininfo`.

1. Get the screens, their resolutions and offsets:

   ```bash
   $ xrandr | grep -w connected  | awk -F'[ \+]' '{print $1,$3,$4}'
   VGA-0 1440x900 1600
   DP-3 1600x900 0
   ```
2. Get the position of the current window

   ```bash
   $ xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep Absolute
    Absolute upper-left X:  1927
    Absolute upper-left Y:  70
   ```

So, by combining the two you should be able to get the resolution of the current screen:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Get screen info
screen1=($(xrandr | grep -w connected  | awk -F'[ +]' '{print $1,$3,$4}' | 
    head -n 1))
screen2=($(xrandr | grep -w connected  | awk -F'[ +]' '{print $1,$3,$4}' | 
    tail -n 1))

## Figure out which screen is to the right of which
if [ ${screen1[2]} -eq 0  ]
then
    right=(${screen2[@]});
    left=(${screen1[@]});
else
    right=(${screen1[@]});
    left=(${screen2[@]});

fi

## Get window position
pos=$(xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep "Absolute upper-left X" | 
      awk '{print $NF}')

## Which screen is this window displayed in? If $pos
## is greater than the offset of the rightmost screen,
## then the window is on the right hand one
if [ "$pos" -gt "${right[2]}" ]
then
    echo "${right[0]} : ${right[1]}"    
else
    echo "${left[0]} : ${left[1]}"    
fi
```

The script will print the name and resolution of the current screen.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was not aware of this xdotool. My window manager unfortunately do not support 'getactivewindow' but a `eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)` will do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: If `xrandr` labels one of the screens as the primary one, this will throw off the `awk` field extraction. Including a `sed` command to delete the primary label will fix that: `xrandr | grep -w connected  | sed 's/primary //' | awk -F'[ +]' '{print $1,$3,$4}'`

Answer (score 3):

I've modified @terdon's (excellent) solution so that it will work with any number of monitors stacked horizontally and/or vertically, and changed the way the offsets are grabbed from xrandr (it wasn't working on my setup, perhaps caused by a change in the xrandr output format).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OFFSET_RE="\+([-0-9]+)\+([-0-9]+)"

# Get the window position
pos=($(xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | 
  sed -nr "s/^.*geometry .*$OFFSET_RE.*$/\1 \2/p"))

# Loop through each screen and compare the offset with the window
# coordinates.
while read name width height xoff yoff
do
  if [ "${pos[0]}" -ge "$xoff" \
    -a "${pos[1]}" -ge "$yoff" \
    -a "${pos[0]}" -lt "$(($xoff+$width))" \
    -a "${pos[1]}" -lt "$(($yoff+$height))" ]
  then
    monitor=$name   
  fi
done < <(xrandr | grep -w connected |
  sed -r "s/^([^ ]*).*\b([-0-9]+)x([-0-9]+)$OFFSET_RE.*$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/" |
  sort -nk4,5)

# If we found a monitor, echo it out, otherwise print an error.
if [ ! -z "$monitor" ]
then
  echo $monitor
  exit 0
else
  echo "Couldn't find any monitor for the current window." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

It is also worth noting that `xdotool` can output the screen that a window is on, but, if you are using Xinerama, which makes all your monitors appear as one large screen, this will only ever output a 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version I hacked together in Python that is based on GTK and does not rely on (parsing the output of) command line tools.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk

disp=Gdk.Display.get_default()
scr=disp.get_default_screen()
win_pos=scr.get_active_window().get_origin()
print("win: %d x %d" % (win_pos.x, win_pos.y))
rect=disp.get_monitor_at_point(win_pos.x, win_pos.y).get_geometry()
print("monitor: %d x %d" % (rect.width, rect.height))
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Great! But Gdk.Screen.get_active_window is deprecated. Any recommendations?

Comment: No, the alternatives that I found back then seem complicated (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027923). I have not tried it but maybe simply using 0 in place of `win_pos.x` and `win_pos.y` works too then the call to `get_active_window()` can be removed completely (but I feared there might be problems thus I chose to rather use the deprecated function as long as it works).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I couldn't get @adam-bowen's answer working with a tiling window manager, some minor edits to use mouse coordinates worked though.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Print's the current screen index (zero based).
#
# Modified from:
# https://superuser.com/a/992924/240907

OFFSET_RE="\+([-0-9]+)\+([-0-9]+)"

# Get the window position
eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)"

# Loop through each screen and compare the offset with the window
# coordinates.
monitor_index=0
while read name width height xoff yoff
do
    if [ "${X}" -ge "$xoff" \
      -a "${Y}" -ge "$yoff" \
      -a "${X}" -lt "$(($xoff+$width))" \
      -a "${Y}" -lt "$(($yoff+$height))" ]
    then
        monitor=$name
        break
    fi
    ((monitor_index++))
done < <(xrandr | grep -w connected |
    sed -r "s/^([^ ]*).*\b([-0-9]+)x([-0-9]+)$OFFSET_RE.*$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/" |
    sort -nk4,5)

# If we found a monitor, echo it out, otherwise print an error.
if [ ! -z "$monitor" ]
then
    # echo $monitor
    echo $monitor_index
    exit 0
else
    echo "Couldn't find any monitor for the current window." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: very cool use of eval, never thought about evaluating the response from shell tools. makes sense why theyre formatted like this.