# Get the display resolution a window is on in a multi monitor set up

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, resolution, shell-script, manjaro

I have a 3 monitors set up (one is 1080p, the other 900p). I'm editing a window tiling bash script that needs to retrieve the resolution of the display an active window is on.

https://superuser.com/a/992924 offers a script to do so but returns an error.
xdotool only returns the resolution of the primary display
xdpyinfo and xwininfo return the total resolution of the 3 displays

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following AFH advice and based on http://www.doknowevil.net/tag/multiple-monitors/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/207685/is-it-possible-to-place-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xfce i came with this script which is a bit complicated because my 3 screens setup is not horizontal and the primary one is of different resolution.

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsizes the window to full height and 50% width and moves into upper right corner


function getActiveWindowID
{
activeWinID=$(xdotool getactivewindow )
echo $activeWinID
}

function getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition
{
activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xPosLine=$(xwininfo -id $activeWinID | grep "Absolute upper-left X")
xPos=${xPosLine:25}
echo $xPos
}

function getActiveWindowVerticalPosition
{
activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
yPosLine=$(xwininfo -id $activeWinID | grep "Absolute upper-left Y")
yPos=${yPosLine:25}
echo $yPos
}

function getActiveWindowWidth
{
activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xWidthLine=$(xwininfo -id $activeWinID | grep "Width")
xWidth=${xWidthLine:8}
echo $xWidth
}

function getActiveWindowHeight
{
activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xHeightLine=$(xwininfo -id $activeWinID | grep "Height")
xHeight=${xHeightLine:8}
echo $xHeight
}

function getActiveWindowCurrentMonitorHorizontal
{

activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xPos=$(getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition)
yPos=$(getActiveWindowVerticalPosition)



if [ $xPos -ge 1920 ] || [ $yPos -le 900 ]; then


monitorwidth=1440
echo $monitorwidth

else     
monitorwidth=1920
echo $monitorwidth


fi

}

function getActiveWindowCurrentMonitorVertical
{

activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xPos=$(getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition)
yPos=$(getActiveWindowVerticalPosition)




if [ $xPos -ge 1920 ] || [ $yPos -le 900 ]; then


monitorheight=873 
echo $monitorheight 
else     

monitorheight=1054
echo $monitorheight

fi

}
function getActiveScreenDistHorizontal
{

activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xPos=$(getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition)
yPos=$(getActiveWindowVerticalPosition)




if [ $xPos -ge 1920 ]; then
activescreendisthorizontal=1920
echo $activescreendisthorizontal
else
if [ $yPos -le 900 ]; then
activescreendisthorizontal=480
echo $activescreendisthorizontal
else
activescreendisthorizontal=0
echo $activescreendisthorizontal
fi
fi  
}

function getActiveScreenDistVertical
{

activeWinID=$(getActiveWindowID)
xPos=$(getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition)
yPos=$(getActiveWindowVerticalPosition)




if [ $xPos -ge 1920 ]; then
activescreendistvertical=438
echo $activescreendisvertical
else
if [ $yPos -le 900 ]; then

activescreendistvertical=0
echo $activescreendistvertical
else
activescreendistvertical=900
echo $activescreendistvertical
fi  
fi  
}

#define MARGINS IN PIXELS
TOPMARGIN=0
RIGHTMARGIN=0
LEFTMARGIN=0
BOTTOMMARGIN=0
# get width of screen and height of screen
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(getActiveWindowCurrentMonitorHorizontal)
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(getActiveWindowCurrentMonitorVertical)

xPos=$(getActiveWindowHorizontalPosition)
yPos=$(getActiveWindowVerticalPosition)



AVAILABLE_WIDTH=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH - $RIGHTMARGIN -$LEFTMARGIN))
AVAILABLE_HEIGHT=$(( $SCREEN_HEIGHT - $TOPMARGIN - $BOTTOMMARGIN))

# new width and height
W=$(( $AVAILABLE_WIDTH / 2))

H=$(( $AVAILABLE_HEIGHT))


# Available coordinates
activescreendisthorizontal=$(getActiveScreenDistHorizontal)
activescreendistvertical=$(getActiveScreenDistVertical)

XLEFT=$(($activescreendisthorizontal+$LEFTMARGIN))
XRIGHT=$(($XLEFT+$LEFTMARGIN+$W ))
YTOP=$(($activescreendistvertical+$TOPMARGIN))
YBOTTOM=$(( $TOPMARGIN+$H ))

# Actual new coordinates
X=$XRIGHT
Y=$YTOP

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r 
:ACTIVE: -e 10,$X,$Y,$W,$H
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you want, but the following command will get the position and dimensions of your shell:

```
$ wmctrl -plG|grep -E "^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ $PPID "
0x0560000b  1 2481   10   47   1352 386  Lenovo-Ubuntu Terminal
```

That is simplistic, because it works only from the initial shell; to work from a sub-shell, you will need:

```
$ wmctrl -plG|grep -E "^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ $(pid=$PPID; until [ "`ps -p $pid -o comm= | grep -i term`" ]; do pid=`ps -p $pid -o ppid=`; done; echo $pid) "
0x0560000b  1 2481   10   47   1352 386  Lenovo-Ubuntu Terminal
```

That assumes that your terminal contains `term` in its name: you may need a different way to identify your terminal (sorry about the long line, but most of it lies within the search string).

You can find out the dimensions of your connected monitors by typing:

```
$ xrandr | grep ' connected'
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
```

After the dimensions, the `+0+0` and `+1366+0` are the X- and Y-axis offsets of each monitor within the global screen.

In order to find out the monitor where the terminal is displayed, you will need to compare the X-axis (between the '+' signs) with the fourth field in the `wmctrl` output to find the rightmost monitor whose X-axis is less than the X-position of the terminal.

In the examples I've shown, the terminal's X-position is `10`, which is greater than `0`, the X-axis of `LVDS1`, but less than `1366`, the X-axis of `HDMI1`, so the terminal is on `LVDS1` whose dimensions are therefore `1366x768`.

In contrast the `wmctrl` command on a terminal in the other screen gave:

```
0x0740000f 1 12147 1466 46 2356 966 Lenovo-Ubuntu xterm
```

Here `1466` is greater than both `0` and `1366`, so the rightmost monitor is `HDMI1`, with dimensions `1920x1080`.

Note that a terminal may straddle two monitors: what I've described will find the leftmost of these, but you can check some of the other fields if you want to do something different in this case.

You will need some complex scripting to make the comparisons, and I don't intend to do that for you, but I hope you have enough information to get started.